# Hibernate Many to one updating foreign key to null inspite of CASCADE.ALL

Tags: spring, jpa, foreign-keys

The annotation mappedBy ideally should always be used in the Parent side (Cities class) of the bi directional relationship, in this case it should be in Cities class pointing to the member variable 'city' of the Child class (Theatre class)

The annotation @JoinColumn is used to specify a mapped column for joining an entity association, this annotation can be used in any class (Parent or Child) but it should ideally be used only in one side (either in parent class or in Child class not in both) here in this case i used it in the Child side (Branch class) of the bi directional relationship indicating the foreign key in the Branch class.

So when i hit the service via PostMan to check whether my post request is working or not. I see the foreign key column is not getting updated properly. I mean the value is set as null. I have given the image of the db as well incase if you guys wanted to take a look.

**Cities**:

```
@Entity
public class Cities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    Long cityId;
    String cityName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="city", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Threatres> movies = new ArrayList<Threatres>();

    public Cities() {
        super();
    }

    public List<Threatres> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Threatres> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    public Long getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(Long cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

}
```

**Threatre**:

```
@Entity
public class Threatres {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long threatreId;
    String nameOfThreatres;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cityId")
    private Cities city;

    public Threatres() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getThreatreId() {
        return threatreId;
    }

    public void setThreatreId(Long threatreId) {
        this.threatreId = threatreId;
    }

    public Cities getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(Cities city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Long getThreatres() {
        return threatreId;
    }

    public void setThreatres(Long threatreId) {
        this.threatreId = threatreId;
    }

    public String getNameOfThreatres() {
        return nameOfThreatres;
    }

    public void setNameOfThreatres(String nameOfThreatres) {
        this.nameOfThreatres = nameOfThreatres;
    }

}
```

**MyServiceClass**

```
    @Service
        public class MasterService implements CityService, MoviesService, ThreatresService {

            @Autowired
            CitiesRepository cityRepository;
            @Autowired
            MoviesRepository moviesRepository;
            @Autowired
            ThreatresRepository threatresRepository;

            @Override
            public void saveCities(Cities cities) {
                cityRepository.save(cities);

            }

            @Override
            public void saveMovies(Movies movies) {
                moviesRepository.save(movies);

            }

            @Override
            public void saveThreatres(Threatres threatres) {
                threatresRepository.save(threatres);
            }

            @Override
            public List<Cities> findAllCities() {
                return (List<Cities>) cityRepository.findAll();

            }

            @Override
            public Cities findAllCityById(Long id) {

                return cityRepository.findByCityId(id);
            }

        }
```

**Controller Class**

```
   `

@RestController
        public class HomeController {

            @Autowired
            CityService cityService;

            @Autowired
            MoviesService moviesService;

            @Autowired
            ThreatresService threatresService;

            @GetMapping("/")
            public void getLoginPage() {

            }

            public void getAllCitites() {

            }

            @PostMapping(value = "/saveCities")
            public void saveCities(@RequestBody Cities cities) {
                cityService.saveCities(cities);
            }

            @PostMapping(value = "/saveMovies")
            public void saveMovies(@RequestBody Movies movies) {
                moviesService.saveMovies(movies);
            }

            @PostMapping(value = "/saveThreatres")
            public void saveThreatres(@RequestBody Threatres threatres) {
                threatresService.saveThreatres(threatres);

            }
        @GetMapping("/finaAllCities")
        public List<Cities> getAllCites() {

            return cityService.findAllCities();

        }

        @GetMapping("/finaAllCitiesbyId/{id}")
        public Cities getCityById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            return cityService.findAllCityById(id);

        }

    }`
```

Please see below image to check PostMan data for a post request.

**Request**
[image: Request]

[Database Image: You can see the CityId in the table threatres is getting  populated with null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTn2e.png)

Comment: How do you construct & persist and what do you persist? Can you add the code?

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere? What does a Postman request (presentation/communication layer) has to do with Hibernate (database layer)?

Comment: @pirho Hey Sorry folks if I question is unclear this is my first post. What I am trying to do is I just want to test my service via a postman. Here the problem I am facing is it is not updating the foreign key column in the database when I use a bidirectional relationship.